# Change cursor to hand when I hover over a button

Tags: c#, button, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, mouse-cursor

I want to change the cursor to hand when hovering over a button, for example, I have this button :

```
<Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="229,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="107" Width="170" Grid.RowSpan="2">
     <Button.Template>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
             <Grid>
                 <Grid.Background>
                     <ImageBrush ImageSource="africa/picture17.png"/>
                 </Grid.Background>
                 <ContentPresenter/>
             </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

How to change the cursor to hand when I hover over the button? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Store 8 and C#-XAML.

Answer (score 137):

You can do this by changing the `Cursor` property:

```
<Button Cursor="Hand" .../>
```

Comment: Works just fine for me in VS 2013, version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: Great, but it could (should) be done in styles. What if I want this on al the buttons.

Answer (score 26):

You need to use `Style` for buttons, could you write in window resource or in button's style:

```xml
<Style>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: You'll need to set the target type on the style for this to work. eg `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">`

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `Mouse.OverrideCursor`:

```
myButton.MouseEnter += (s,e) => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;

myButton.MouseLeave += (s,e) => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Comment: By some reason, this was the way to go... so thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

Use `Visual State Manager`

Update your `XAML` to be like this

```
<Button Content="Beh}"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonHover}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Cursor)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Cursor>Hand</Cursor>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Button>
```

Comment: i'm really sorry but i didn't use triggers before .. can you please explain more how to do it by triggers ?

Comment: @user3542555 Sorry, didn't see it was WinRT. Updated my answer. Use `VSM`

Comment: no it is ok .. ok then where do i put my button template inside your code ?

Comment: `<Button.Template>` Either before `VisualStateManager` or after